# Managing disk usage of Redis in Laravel when used for queue + broadcast driver?

Tags: laravel, redis, diskspace

I am currently running a Laravel application which is using a MariaDB database for most of its persistence, and is using a Redis database for its queue and broadcast drivers. I am using laravel-echo-server for my broadcasting.

So far it's working fine, but I am noticing that the Redis database is increasing quite a bit in size, even though I only use it for holding jobs in the queue and for the event broadcasting.

Do I need to run some type of periodic clean up job? Am I missing some detail? I don't recall anything about having to clean up completed jobs or past events in the Laravel docs.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update on this: the Redis disk space seems to fluctuate both up and down - I saw it hover on nothing, jump to 144MB then 250MB+, and this morning was just 8MB after we had a period of little activity overnight.

It really seems to be more of a disk cache rather than anything else, so it doesn't seem this needs maintenance after all. Case closed :-).